# The project was not built since its build path is incomplete - Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Oxygen and imported a project from git hub as a java project and when I tried to build the application it is giving me the following error under Problems view:

> Description-
> The project was not built since its build path is
>   incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
>   org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList. Fix the build path then try
>   building this project
>
> Type-
> The type org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList cannot be resolved.
>   It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tried to fix the issue by performing actions:

1. Right click-->Properties-->Build path-->Removed the library and then
   selected the workspace default library--->cleaned and built the
   project. But, the error still persists.
2. Also tried to add org.eclipse.emf.common-2.12.0.jar file to the
   project build path. But this raised to some more errors in the
   workspace.

Comment: what github project are you building? in case it is a maven-based build (which is likely), you should import is as a maven project. Same if it is gradle-based

Comment: You may have to install EMF modules for Eclipse before. Maybe from https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.emf.emf or a Maven dependency is missing, that you could download from here : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.emf ?

Comment: It's not clear what issue you are facing. Could you share the Gitub repo link so that we could try importing it and see whether we can reproduce the issue and thus help you.

Comment: Yes sure,the Github repo link is  https://github.com/Open-MBEE/mdk.git